# HTTP Expires header values "0" and "-1"

Tags: http

What is the difference between `Expires: 0` and `Expires: -1` in the HTTP response header? [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21) defines *invalid date formats, especially including the value "0"* as *already expired*. However, some servers (e.g. [www.google.de](http://www.google.de)) reply with `Expires: -1`.

Is there an advantage over using `-1` over `0` or is this even required for some broken HTTP clients?

Comment: It doesn't define `"0"` as "already expired" - it defines "invalid date formats", *including* `"0"`, as "already expired"

Comment: That's correct, thanks for this hint. But it seems to me like "0" should be preferred when specifying an "invalid date format".

Comment: No, the preference (expressed in the next paragraph) is to use a valid date format, containing the same value as the `Date` header, to indicate already expired.

Comment: Thanks again. After trying various servers I couldn't find any one that uses the same value in the _Date_ and _Expires_ field, so I guess this might be some compatibility thing or simplification or just lack of knowledge.

Comment: Question Still Needs an Answer: In 2018, when all the browsers against my site are evergreen, is it better to use 0 or -1.  It is possible that I am encountering corporate caching proxy servers that should prefer 0 or “-1” to accomplish no caching – but I do not have good guidance on this.  The spec would imply that 0 is better than -1.  (so why is -1 used everywhere? (old ie detail that may not be relevant anymore))

Answer (score 34):

The problem is in how invalid Expires header processed by Internet Explorer (especially older versions).
IE uses [Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) layout engine and [WinINET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to process HTTP requests. As you may know Expires could be specified in HTTP header

```
Expires: 0
```

or in meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

In second case, Expires became part of the response content (not header content), so it will be [processed by Trident and then propagated to WinINET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/01/31/avoid-using-meta-to-specify-expires-or-pragma-in-html-markup.aspx):

> If WinINET downloads a response with an invalid Expires header (e.g.
>   one that doesn’t contain a valid HTTPDATE value) and no other caching
>   directives, it will mark the document as having expired one hour ago.
>   Trident, however, has no such logic. If you specify an invalid time,
>   Trident grabs the current timestamp and uses that as the expiration.
>   Trident will also use the current timestamp if it encounters the
>   Pragma: no-cache directive. If the user tries to re-navigate to the
>   current document during same exact second that the HTTP/404 was
>   processed, the incorrectly-updated expiration of the existing cache
>   entry will result in it being treated as fresh for that request. If
>   the user hit the Refresh button or F5, the cache would be bypassed and
>   the 404 page would be shown.

In other words `Expires: 0` not always leads to immediate resource expiration, therefore should be avoided and `Expires: [some valid date in the past]` should be used instead.

Comment: That's the "some broken HTTP client" answer I was waiting for and explains the reason for "Expires: -1", thanks! :)

Comment: 3 upvotes? Did anybody even read the answer? According to the article, there is *no difference* between `Expires:-1` and `Expires:0`.

Comment: That's correct. The article only explains an incorrectly handled *Expires=0* in the HTML meta element. Not a single word about *Expires=-1* or other incorrectly handled Expires values in the HTTP header.

Comment: "RFC Note: Never use Expires = 0 to prevent caching." ... however, IE seems to regard this as "never expires" on forms, always displaying the old page after posting new information. IE is safer to use -1. Some browsers refuse -1. So it depends on your traffic and form usage. Lots of IE and forms, use -1

Comment: Thank you. But these tags didn't help me for "go back" and "go forward" in Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132:
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 2018 00:00:01 GMT" />
How can I disable cache for "go back" and "go forward"?

Comment: I checked in Eclipse debugger that servlets do not handle requests from  IE 11, Chrome 63.

Answer (score 13):

Expires: -1
The Expires header specifies when the content should be considered to be out of date. The value -1 indicates that the content expires immediately and would have to be re-requested before being displayed again. 
http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/headers/

max-age=0 simply tells caches (and user agents) the response is stale from the get-go and so they SHOULD revalidate the response (eg. with the If-Not-Modified header) before using a cached copy, whereas, no-cache tells them they MUST revalidate before using a cached copy.

for more info look into http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but my question has been specifically about the difference between `Expires: 0` and `Expires: -1`.

Comment: +1 Though not really an answer to the question, but it's relevant to the topic.  Seems to me if you are trying to to add expires: -1 or 0 you will likely be using the max-age=0 as well.  Probably should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Using "-1" is invalid, and would be treated the same as "0". It should not trigger a reload at all.

Be careful: in some browsers, it may give 1 hour extra or use default expire time for caching.

1- So better to give it a correct old date like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
```

For formal work, I advise to give 
the current date time to meta Expires instead of using Old fixed date ( that will make search engines like google mark your site as old and not be shown on toppers)

2- if your Backend is PHP you can deal with it like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="<?php echo gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()-3600) . ' GMT' ?>" />
```

PS: I give one hour before just for in case.