# GWT IE does not disable caching

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, gwt

In my app IE caches whole content. It seems like *nocache.js is not working? When I jump from one tab to another it cashes everything. Even that I put meta tags for not caching the behavior is the same:

```
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

The manual turn off of caching from Tools -> Internet Options -> Browsing history ... is not proper solution in my case.

My index.html file look like this:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
           <head>
           <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
          <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
           <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
          <script language="javascript" src="myapp/myapp.nocache.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
         <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_someFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
        </body>
          </html>
```

Thanks for help!

EDIT:
Thanks for help, but still problem exist. The method table.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(table.getVisibleRange(), true); is not working under IE. I see only the endless spinner and table content is not loading properly.

Issue has been resolved:
When I have changed Range every time in setVisibleRangeAndClearData(table.getVisibleRange(), true); the page is loading every time from server. It seems that under IE RangeChange Event is not firing properly (at least in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I read that because of a bug in IE, those lines may need to be nearer the end of an html file.
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881

Also, it's advised to use -1 in place of 0 for the expires value.
[HTTP Expires header values "0" and "-1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357430/http-expires-header-values-0-and-1)

Let me know how those work for you.

Comment: Hmm, that stinks.
Have you tried the solution posted on this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: Yes, and still without luck :(

Comment: One other thing I've seen in several examples is to add a parameter that doesn't really mean anything to src entry in the script tag, like ?ver=1.0.1. That is supposed to force reload, bu tI haven't tried it. And it means tweaking everytime you do a release.

Comment: If you are just dealing with testing right now, CTRL + F5 will clear the cache reload the page so your code/css is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is working for you even after trying all the possible solutions then try with a *trick* that works in all the cases.

If the URL of the page is changed then browser considers it as a separate request and fetches a fresh copy of the page form the server. Simply append a dummy value in the URL if there is no concern from client side as query string for e.g UUID or time in milliseconds to make a new request.