# What's the function of ExpiresAbsolute?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm trying to port a really old and poorly written ASP page to ASP.NET and I came across this line in the "head":

`<meta http-equiv="ExpiresAbsolute" content="0" />`

Tried Google but nothing useful came up.
What does "ExpiresAbsolute" do? I know "Expires" can be set to control caching etc. but the absolute part, I have never seen..

Anyone who can explain this or direct to information?

Comment: Didn't google very hard. *"The `ExpiresAbsolute` property specifies the date and time at which a page cached on a browser expires. If the user returns to the same page before that date and time, the cached version is displayed. If a time is not specified, the page expires at midnight of that day. If a date is not specified, the page expires at the given time on the day that the script runs."* In the context of a `<meta>` tag is useless the actually true `<meta>` tag value is `expires`.

Comment: Yes, I found the keyword, but only in it's `response.ExpiresAbsolute` form. It's when used in the http-equiv form I'm interested in.

Comment: Like I already explained it doesn't have one that is a Classic ASP specific way of setting the `expires` HTTP header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExpiresAbsolute` is a property of the `Response` object in Classic ASP and in this context means nothing as there is no valid `http-equiv` of `ExpiresAbsolute`.

> <sup>From [MSDN - Response.ExpiresAbsolute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526058(v=vs.90).aspx)</sup>
> *The ExpiresAbsolute property specifies the date and time at which a page cached on a browser expires. If the user returns to the same page before that date and time, the cached version is displayed. If a time is not specified, the page expires at midnight of that day. If a date is not specified, the page expires at the given time on the day that the script runs.*

The actually correct `http-equiv` value of this for a `<meta>` tag in HTML is `expires`.

```html
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1900 1:00:00 GMT">
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [HTTP Expires header values “0” and “-1”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367872/692942)
- [Using  tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/692942)

Comment: Thanks for the information, it was the use in the `<meta>` tag I needed to know. Then I guess it should be safe to remove as there is no support for the value...

Comment: @Falchion It would appear as though it never worked if it's intention was to force the page to not cache then whoever wrote it failed.